# Tab focus does not reach on disabled input field

Tags: html, wcag

I am working accessibility testing. when I click on tab key to reading all the components, the focus does not reach on input field though input field is in inactive state, not editable. so for the screen reader does the tab focus should reach on input field ? what should be defect resolution ?

HTML

```
<input class =‘value ’ type =‘text’ disabled id=‘value’
```

Another query
Radio button and Checkbox field are disabled so TAB focus does not reach on these field. any keyboard shortcut command ?

Comment: Please post the HTML in question. If I understand you correctly, there's an `<input disabled>` element. If so, then it's correct that you cannot TAB to the input. A screen reader user can still navigate to the input, just not with the TAB key.  They can use the down arrow to walk the DOM, or a shortcut key to navigate to the next input (usually the 'E' key). The screen reader user cannot type in the field because it's disabled, but they can still navigate to it.

Comment: @slugolicious inspect element I can see the input disabled.. thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm moving my comment to the answer area so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post the HTML in question.

If I understand you correctly, there's an `<input disabled>` element. If so, then it's correct that you cannot <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the input.

A screen reader user can still navigate to the input, just not with the TAB key. They can use the down arrow to walk the DOM, or a shortcut key to navigate to the next input (usually the 'E' key). The screen reader user cannot type in the field because it's disabled, but they can still navigate to it.

Comment: when screen reader navigates through the disabled input using command E. I can see it reads input element append with unavailable. so my doubt is if user press Tab key on disabled input, the focus is not reached so should the focus is reached or not ? how to fix this issue ?

Comment: There’s nothing to fix. It’s working as designed when you use the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: is this expected according to the wcag guideline and for the blind user perspective.  does the tab focus reach on disabled text box ? by providing the tabindex =-1 to the element.

Comment: `tabindex` is not related to this. It is expected behavior to not be able to TAB to input elements with the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: I have reported this as a defect so I need to change it as not a defect ? Or what changes do we need to make the element accessible ? read only attribute instead of disabled attribute is it right ?

Comment: I have updated my question. kindly have a look into it

Comment: You can do a search for the screen reader you're using and "keyboard shortcuts" to find documentation on how to use a screen reader.  Both [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation) and [JAWS](https://www.freedomscientific.com/training/jaws/hotkeys/#nqkwb) have information on their websites about keyboard commands.

Comment: I do not get any information, but I tried clicking on different keys and I got that keyboard shortcuts to locate the elements like R for radio button, x for checkbox. Thank you

Comment: *"I do not get any information"*  I don't understand that comment. You looked at both links I posted and couldn't find the shortcut keys? The links pointed directly to that section. They both show R for radio and X for checkbox.

Comment: sorry, I didn't check that link. Now I got the different keyboard commands. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I want to know the difference between WCAG 3.3.2 labels or instruction and 1.3.5 identify input purpose as I unable to post any new questions.